# Cannot read property 'on' of undefined (TypeError)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am coding a music discord bot with `discord.js` and I keep getting this error:

```
client.on('warn', console.warn);
       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

So I wonder what it is. I have the bot code down below. Take a look through if you want and if you know how to fix it I would be happy.

The bot code:

```
const { client } = require('discord.js');
const { TOKEN, PREFIX } = require('./config');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');


client.on('warn', console.warn);

client.on('error', console.error);

client.on('ready', console.log('Primary systems online'));

client.on('disconnect', console.log('So you know i disconnected, i will reconnect soon...'));

client.on('reconnecting', console.log('I am reconnecting'));

client.on('message', async msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return undefined;
    if (msg.content.startswith(PREFIX)) return undefined;
    const args = msg.content.split(' ');

    if (msg.content.startswith('${PREFIX}play')) {
       const voiceChannel = msg.member.voiceChannel;
       if (!voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('you need to be in a voice channel to use this function.')
       const permissions = voiceChannel.premissionsfor(msg.client.user)
       if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) {
            return msg.channel.send('i cant go there give me the permission to go there')
       }
       if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')){
           return msg.channel.send('i cannot speak here! I dont have the rights too')
       }

       try {
            var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
       } catch (error) {

            console.error('i could not join the voice channel: ${error}');
            return msg.channel.send('i could not join the voice channel');
       }

       const dispatcher = connection.playstream(ytdl(args[1]))
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('song ended!')
                voiceChannel.leave();
            })
            .on('error', error => {
                console.error(error)
            });
        dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(5 / 5);
    }
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: but then this error comes up:
 const client = new Discord.Client();
                       ^

ReferenceError: Discord is not defined (ninja edit got that working but now i cant get something else working

Comment: throw new errors.ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^ this is the thing i cant get working

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're setting the client by requiring Dicord.js, but you should create the client by setting it as a new instance of [`Discord.Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client).
Try to do this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Then you can keep the rest of the code.

Comment: You likely can keep using the same syntax, but just need to capitalize the C, so `const { Client } = require('discord.js');`, however you will still need to instantiate it with `const client = new Client();`

Comment: Yeah, I just thought it would be better to keep Discord.js declared in case you need another class

Comment: this is the hole error:


events.js:200
    throw new errors.ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined

Comment: This error is not about the problem in the question: it's probably the result of some broken `client.on(...)`. Check your `client.on(...)` statements and look if you are always passing functions as listeners (`client.on("event", -> listener <-)`), since it says that you are passing `undefined` as listener somewhere in your code